# ftdi_sio working fine until I use windows

Tags: debian, drivers

I have a target reader that use ftdi_sio drivers.

First time I plug in, **lsusb** respond:

```
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

And **dmesg** respond:
several messages and something like it was `attached to ttyUSB0`

Later I use it in Windows7 and now it says:

**lsusb**

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0403:0000 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd H4SMK 7 Port Hub
```

dmesg

```
[ 2651.352022] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci_hcd
[ 2651.839028] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=0000
[ 2651.839035] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2651.839040] usb 4-1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 2651.839044] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 2651.839048] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: ********
```

I think nothing has changed and I need it to work like before.

It is Debian7 server.
Linux server 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run in the same problem.

I programmed the correct Product ID using FT_PROG again.
You need to edit the INF file of the FTDI driver, so the device with the wrong IDs is recognized by the driver.

All seems to work fine for now using Linux -- the stick is recognized again.

When I plug the stick back to a Windows system, the product ID is changed to 0000 again.

So, program it again, and using the stick on linux only works for me.

Comment: http://www.golem.de/news/ftdi-windows-treiber-kann-bastelrechner-beschaedigen-1410-110039.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Markus it works!
Steps:

1. Start Windows and connect device.
2. It won't install properly so you have to edit ftdibus.inf and ftdiport.inf and replace PID_6001 to PID_0000
3. Reinstall drivers
4. Open FT_PROG and load device.
5. Change idproduct to 6001 and clic program.